# Segmentation Fault when linking c++ and assembly

Tags: c++, assembly

So I am trying to link a simple assembly script with c++, and so far no luck.

Assembly Script

```
section .data
global getebx


getebx:
mov eax, 0x0
cpuid
mov eax, ebx
ret
```

c++

```
#include <iostream>


extern "C" unsigned getebx();

int main (){

std::cout << (const char *)getebx()<< std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

And to build i am simply running the following commands.

```
nasm -f elf32 cpuidtest.asm
g++ -m32 -g main.cc cpuidtest.o
```

When I ran the executable I got a Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) error. So my next instinct was to take it to gdb. Here is what it returned:

```
   program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0xf7da0e86 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

How can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling convention mandates you must preserve some registers. In your case, that applies to `ebx`. You should modify your code to save and restore that, such as:

```
getebx:
push ebx
mov eax, 0x0
cpuid
mov eax, ebx
pop ebx
ret
```

Also, putting code into the `.data` section isn't the best idea ;)

Furthermore, `ebx` does not hold a string (a pointer to char) so you can not print it like that. It holds 4 characters, so something like this works better:

```
int main (){
    unsigned ebx = getebx();
    std::cout << std::string((char*)&ebx, 4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't  quite fix the problem (thanks for the tips though) could it be a problem in the c++ side of things? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: That fixed everything, thank you for your help. (I cant believe I didn't see that).